# page post back when i use ToolkitScriptManager On MasterPage does not work just for part of page

Tags: asp.net

in the master page i was using ScriptManager so in the content page according to below markup i had post back just for part of page.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
 <ContentTemplate>
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProjectDocument" runat="server" Height="16px" AppendDataBoundItems="True"  
     Width="212px" onselectedindexchanged="ddlProjectDocument_SelectedIndexChanged" 
    AutoPostBack="True" onload="ddlProjectDocument_Load" 
    style="font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace" >

    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0">(select a value)</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<br />



</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlProjectDocument"  />


</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

now i have added combo box to my content page so i remove ScriptManager and place ToolkitScriptManager on Master Page according to below markup for master page, now when i use drop down list control post back happen for complete page not just part like before, how i can solve this problem?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Untitled Page</title>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<style type="text/css">
    .style1
    {
        width: 40%;
        font-size:large;
    }
</style>
<link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 </head>
 <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">


    <ajaxtoolkit:toolkitscriptmanager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </ajaxtoolkit:toolkitscriptmanager>
```

markup of new content page is like below:

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProjectDocument" runat="server" Height="16px" AppendDataBoundItems="True"  
     Width="212px" onselectedindexchanged="ddlProjectDocument_SelectedIndexChanged" 
    AutoPostBack="True" onload="ddlProjectDocument_Load" 
    style="font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace" >

    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0">(select a value)</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<br />

<ajaxtoolkit:ComboBox ID="ComboBox1" runat="server" onload="ComboBox1_Load" 
     AutoCompleteMode="Suggest" 
     style="font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace" >

</ajaxtoolkit:ComboBox>



</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlProjectDocument"  />


</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because AutoPostBack=true is on inside of the panel, it will cause the postback.

I was able to get your example working using:

`<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlProjectDocument" />`

Hope this helps!